# attach event to jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have this:

```
$("#term").autocomplete({
  minLength: 2,
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
      dataType: 'JSONP',
      data: {
        format: 'json',
        q: 'select * from xml where url="http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=' + escape(request.term) + '"'
      },
      success: function(data) {
        response($.map(data.query.results.toplevel.CompleteSuggestion, function(item) {
          return { label: item.suggestion.data, value: item.suggestion.data };
        }));
      }
    });
  }
});
```

So the autocomplete has a build in for keyup event. But how do I give the same 'function( request, response )' when clicking something (= ul li in this case)? How do I attach onclick event to do the autocomplete?

here is live version: [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/epikim/2/edit#javascript,live)

Comment: What do you mean "when clicking something". When clicking what ? A completely external element or something part of the autocomplete ?

Comment: The autocomplete function gives the json results as ul, li below the element with `term` as id. So Youss wants to know how to retrieve the value from that selection and use it (I think)

Comment: Didier Ghys Hi, I mean clicking a list item would give another search/results (by the value of that item)

Comment: @JP Hellemons Yes that is exactly what I want:)

Comment: @3nigma You would have to type something..

Comment: @Didier Ghys First, it is a very important question (related to my website that is) and second, I don't feel like I was really under stud in my previous questions (maybe I was asking the wrong way..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. As far as I understood, the plugin provides a "search" method to programmatically initiate a search, like you would if you were typing in the input field directly.

The use is the following:

```
$('#term').autocomplete('search', 'Napoleon');
```

If you want to start a new suggestion each time an element is selected in the menu, you can use the `select` event. It is trigerred when an element is selected from the suggestion list, either by cliking an item, or with keyboard:

```
$("#term").autocomplete({
    ...,
    select: function(e, ui) {
        $('#term').val(ui.item.value).autocomplete('search', ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

The property `ui.item` is the data item that was selected.

I've set-up a demo where cliking a button will search for the term associate to a "data-" attribute:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/3eemZ/)**

Further reading:

- ["search" method of autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#method-search)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replay. I think Im looking for a way to use the 'select' event which will put value of the list item in the input but instead of closing the ul li it would have to request again which will lead to a different (xml) list  [link]http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select[link]

Comment: The autocomplete plugin was absolutely not made to work like that so... good luck. It also does not make much sense in terms of UX and Usability. Keep in mind that people like to use things they are familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

Use `select` event and then trigger autocomplete search by passing the value which you can get  from the event arguments.

```
select: function(e, ui){
    $("#term").autocomplete('search', ui.item.value);
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/24mD8/3/)**

Comment: Thanks allot, This is over my head coding:)

Comment: Pretty much looks like the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9016998/123127) I gave 5 hours ago...

Comment: Sorry, I accepted your answer (much on my mind and so little time makes me confused sometimes..)

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit lost with the ) and } in my snippet, but you should use the `select` option

```
$("#term").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
            dataType: 'JSONP',
            data: {
                format: 'json',
                q: 'select * from xml where url="http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=' + escape(request.term) + '"'
            },
            success: function(data) {
                response($.map(data.query.results.toplevel.CompleteSuggestion, 
                    function(item) {
                        return { label: item.suggestion.data, value: item.suggestion.data };
                    }));
            } /* end succes function */
            }); /* end ajax function */
    }, /* end source function */
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
       $("#term").val(ui.item.value); /* to set the clicked value in the input */
       $("#btn").click(); /* to submit the form, replace with your button*/
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** I added some comments for myself to check if there where missing brackets (lol)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually need to perform search when clicking a list item not a submit button Something like  `$("li a").click();` or `$(".ui-menu-item a").click();` which will trigger a second request

Comment: Lol, didn't knew that you wanted to use it to search again. Though I was the first with the `select` solution :P